# Circular mean incorrect

Tags: r, geometry, trigonometry, angle

I want to estimate the mean and spread of angles per year for moving individuals. Data set will be pasted at the end.

This is what I have so far:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(sf)
    library(lwgeom)
    library(geosphere)
    library(circular)
```

This gets the  bearings of locations from the point

```
HI=data.frame(x=rep(151.9155, 217), y=rep(-23.44288, 217))

bears<-trips%>%
  mutate(bearing=geosphere::bearing(st_multipoint(cbind(HI$x, HI$y)), 
                                    st_multipoint(cbind(.$x, .$y))),
     bearing360 = (bearing + 360) %% 360)
```

Get mean direction and variance

```
mnbears<-bears%>%
      mutate(bearing360 = circular(bearing)) %>%
      group_by(Year) %>%
      summarise(mnDir = mean.circular(bearing), var = var.circular(bearing)) %>%
      mutate(mnDir = conversion.circular(mnDir, units = 'degrees', modulo = 'asis', zero = 0), 
           var = conversion.circular(circular(var), units = 'degrees'))
```

Throw them together for ggplot

```
    jb<-left_join(bears, mnbears) 
    
    
    bDist<-ggplot(jb, aes(x = bearing360, fill = Year)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 15, boundary = -7.5, colour = "black", size = .25) +
                geom_segment(aes(x = mnDir, y = 10, xend = mnDir, yend = 20), col='black') +
      geom_segment(aes(x = mnDir-(var/2), y = 20, xend = mnDir+(var/2), yend = 20), col='black') +
      guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
      coord_polar() +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,360),
                         breaks = seq(0, 360, by = 90),
                         minor_breaks = seq(0, 360, by = 45)) +
      scale_fill_brewer() +
      facet_grid(~Year) +
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
            panel.grid = element_line(color = "grey"),
            strip.background = element_blank(),
            strip.text.x = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 11),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank())
    
    
    bDist
```

[image]

Hopefully from the plots you can see the estimate mean and variance is really wrong (indicated by the black 'T' shapes)! I can't figure out how to get the estimates correct. I suspect it is some technical circular data concept that I haven't experienced. Either something to do with the 'modulo' settings or the direction in which bearing was measured is my best get but I've tried all combinations I can think of.

How can I get the correct estimate for the mean and variance?

Data (trips) for reprex:

```
|Year |        x|         y|
|:----|--------:|---------:|
|2019 | 151.3549| -22.51087|
|2020 | 151.7959| -23.57362|
|2020 | 151.8792| -23.48739|
|2020 | 151.8875| -23.54251|
|2020 | 151.8026| -23.43382|
|2020 | 151.8458| -23.56966|
|2020 | 151.9292| -23.38716|
|2020 | 151.8155| -23.03113|
|2020 | 151.8536| -23.13598|
|2020 | 151.8660| -23.49086|
|2020 | 151.8625| -23.49980|
|2020 | 151.8288| -23.47545|
|2020 | 151.8630| -23.49681|
|2020 | 151.8740| -23.48952|
|2020 | 151.8401| -23.47993|
|2020 | 151.8583| -23.49799|
|2020 | 151.8502| -23.46673|
|2020 | 151.8654| -23.49062|
|2020 | 151.8626| -23.51057|
|2020 | 151.8958| -23.52990|
|2020 | 151.7507| -23.45382|
|2020 | 151.7409| -23.45942|
|2020 | 151.8557| -23.50075|
|2020 | 151.8834| -23.58453|
|2020 | 151.9233| -23.60095|
|2020 | 151.8564| -23.43141|
|2020 | 151.9685| -23.65540|
|2020 | 151.7681| -23.57841|
|2020 | 151.7986| -23.65532|
|2020 | 151.7582| -23.70650|
|2020 | 151.7328| -23.48951|
|2020 | 151.8876| -23.61944|
|2020 | 151.8471| -23.26857|
|2020 | 151.9005| -23.38162|
|2020 | 151.8629| -23.63405|
|2020 | 151.8518| -23.41013|
|2020 | 152.0313| -23.41983|
|2020 | 151.3282| -23.71458|
|2020 | 151.8332| -23.33175|
|2020 | 151.8134| -23.33415|
|2020 | 151.7663| -23.38577|
|2020 | 151.7972| -23.43462|
|2020 | 151.7085| -23.29203|
|2020 | 151.8643| -23.42937|
|2020 | 151.8519| -23.32817|
|2020 | 151.9212| -23.58503|
|2020 | 151.8469| -23.51568|
|2020 | 151.7841| -23.43410|
|2020 | 151.8045| -23.40979|
|2020 | 151.8764| -23.78642|
|2020 | 151.3802| -23.44065|
|2020 | 151.8101| -23.44553|
|2020 | 151.8493| -23.46276|
|2019 | 151.9488| -23.43558|
|2019 | 152.0061| -23.48749|
|2019 | 151.9449| -23.46720|
|2019 | 152.0566| -23.42244|
|2020 | 151.7048| -23.73499|
|2020 | 151.7205| -23.83130|
|2020 | 151.9030| -23.51964|
|2020 | 151.6201| -23.91792|
|2020 | 151.8511| -23.69530|
|2020 | 151.8494| -23.57195|
|2020 | 151.8912| -23.66548|
|2020 | 151.7875| -23.76454|
|2020 | 151.9273| -23.60010|
|2020 | 151.7049| -23.29387|
|2020 | 151.8574| -23.42830|
|2020 | 151.6925| -23.41902|
|2020 | 151.9542| -23.33343|
|2020 | 151.8367| -23.41281|
|2020 | 151.7874| -23.74106|
|2020 | 151.9670| -23.57370|
|2020 | 152.0281| -23.40727|
|2020 | 151.8325| -23.34148|
|2020 | 151.8641| -23.52120|
|2020 | 151.8446| -23.48096|
|2020 | 151.8731| -23.44420|
|2020 | 152.0092| -23.40491|
|2020 | 151.8099| -23.42122|
|2020 | 151.8518| -23.50224|
|2020 | 151.8691| -23.49820|
|2020 | 151.8528| -23.43173|
|2021 | 151.9299| -23.48949|
|2021 | 151.9988| -23.62274|
|2021 | 152.0649| -23.62837|
|2021 | 151.7091| -23.51718|
|2021 | 151.9607| -23.41935|
|2021 | 152.0153| -23.41470|
|2021 | 151.7294| -23.53706|
|2021 | 151.8953| -23.42542|
|2021 | 151.8300| -23.48532|
|2021 | 151.8654| -23.42682|
|2021 | 151.9111| -23.41984|
|2021 | 152.0536| -23.41074|
|2021 | 152.0548| -23.41915|
|2021 | 151.9443| -23.63787|
|2021 | 152.0069| -23.41399|
|2021 | 152.0580| -23.42258|
|2021 | 151.9596| -23.42265|
|2021 | 151.8786| -23.41094|
|2021 | 151.8852| -23.44104|
|2021 | 151.9388| -23.35891|
|2021 | 151.9058| -23.40970|
|2021 | 151.9490| -23.42408|
|2019 | 151.8181| -23.38416|
|2019 | 150.8755| -22.88907|
|2021 | 152.0784| -23.71287|
|2021 | 152.0142| -23.48147|
|2021 | 152.0238| -23.58956|
|2021 | 151.9565| -23.59669|
|2021 | 151.9782| -23.61075|
|2021 | 151.9784| -23.47652|
|2021 | 152.1223| -23.43406|
|2021 | 151.9975| -23.47265|
|2021 | 151.9509| -23.47858|
|2021 | 151.8659| -23.40042|
|2021 | 151.9835| -23.47445|
|2021 | 151.9942| -23.49223|
|2021 | 152.0362| -23.46816|
|2021 | 152.0086| -23.48778|
|2021 | 151.9413| -23.47545|
|2021 | 151.9886| -23.48856|
|2021 | 151.9430| -23.47246|
|2021 | 151.9817| -23.49972|
|2021 | 151.9993| -23.42002|
|2021 | 152.0099| -23.48919|
|2021 | 151.9259| -23.29711|
|2021 | 151.9757| -23.40455|
|2021 | 152.0466| -23.46832|
|2021 | 152.0223| -23.42812|
|2021 | 152.0749| -23.42492|
|2021 | 151.8081| -23.48507|
|2021 | 151.8238| -23.51239|
|2021 | 151.8305| -23.50929|
|2021 | 151.8562| -23.61330|
|2021 | 151.9660| -23.42000|
|2021 | 152.0922| -23.51141|
|2021 | 151.8327| -23.32961|
|2021 | 151.7930| -23.49821|
|2021 | 151.8765| -23.51462|
|2021 | 151.8296| -23.43750|
|2021 | 151.7995| -23.47485|
|2021 | 151.8632| -23.45549|
|2021 | 151.8266| -23.50840|
|2021 | 151.8700| -23.43128|
|2021 | 151.8665| -23.70580|
|2021 | 151.8225| -23.62326|
|2021 | 151.9601| -23.49017|
|2021 | 151.9737| -23.47956|
|2021 | 151.9673| -23.53141|
|2021 | 151.9732| -23.70913|
|2019 | 151.5390| -23.49592|
|2019 | 151.5404| -23.50782|
|2019 | 151.7217| -23.34590|
|2021 | 151.9210| -23.48402|
|2021 | 151.9782| -23.48022|
|2021 | 151.8481| -23.56943|
|2021 | 152.0031| -23.59803|
|2021 | 152.0144| -23.48938|
|2021 | 151.8186| -23.47955|
|2021 | 151.8250| -23.57878|
|2021 | 151.8225| -23.48596|
|2021 | 151.9910| -23.47478|
|2021 | 151.8382| -23.49800|
|2021 | 151.8084| -23.60350|
|2021 | 151.8023| -23.61190|
|2021 | 151.8164| -23.62010|
|2021 | 151.9611| -23.49243|
|2021 | 151.9564| -23.51577|
|2021 | 151.8836| -23.49689|
|2021 | 152.0077| -23.47821|
|2021 | 151.8216| -23.48753|
|2021 | 151.9700| -23.43557|
|2021 | 152.0044| -23.45532|
|2021 | 152.0447| -23.44921|
|2021 | 151.8647| -23.54219|
|2021 | 151.9037| -23.49741|
|2021 | 151.9136| -23.49116|
|2021 | 151.7988| -23.48745|
|2021 | 152.0451| -23.40705|
|2021 | 152.0415| -23.40918|
|2021 | 152.0157| -23.40652|
|2021 | 151.9719| -23.42479|
|2021 | 151.8049| -23.62434|
|2021 | 151.9203| -23.48346|
|2021 | 151.9228| -23.47228|
|2021 | 151.9705| -23.47643|
|2021 | 151.9705| -23.43327|
|2021 | 151.9284| -23.49097|
|2021 | 151.7945| -23.69604|
|2021 | 151.8789| -23.61902|
|2021 | 151.8977| -23.49126|
|2021 | 151.8814| -23.60803|
|2021 | 151.8250| -23.61652|
|2021 | 151.8473| -23.58226|
|2020 | 151.8334| -23.43713|
|2020 | 151.8650| -23.39184|
|2020 | 151.7018| -23.29463|
|2020 | 151.6709| -23.33659|
|2020 | 152.0276| -23.40897|
|2020 | 151.8111| -23.42271|
|2020 | 151.9733| -23.42767|
|2020 | 152.0211| -23.41244|
|2020 | 151.8712| -23.65240|
|2020 | 151.9095| -23.51222|
|2020 | 151.9301| -23.52330|
|2020 | 151.8817| -23.60455|
|2020 | 151.8553| -23.62631|
|2020 | 151.8530| -23.59368|
|2020 | 151.9107| -23.69545|
|2020 | 151.9766| -23.47657|
|2020 | 152.0145| -23.53364|
|2020 | 151.8122| -23.62238|
|2020 | 151.8008| -23.65538|
|2020 | 151.6813| -22.93562|
|2020 | 151.7781| -22.89655|
```

Comment: Sorry it was supposed to be just 'circular' must have auto-corrected on me. Sorry in R, now tagged.

Comment: According to the help page for `circular::circular()`, the default unit is "radians", whereas you use degrees. Is the problem fixed if you do `mutate(bearing360 = circular(bearing, unit="degrees"))` in the code that generates `mnbears`?

Comment: How did you read that data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, the main problem is that `circular()` by default expects different kind of circular data and when you are working with geographical angles you have to specify the units (degrees), rotation (clockwise) and where zero is located (π/2). When you do this, you will get the correct mean values.

Another problem, however, may arise with the variance. Circular variance varies from 0 to 1. A variance of one means that a variable has a very large spread and a variance of 0 means that all data are concentrated at one point ([Cremers & Klugkist 2018](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2018.02040/full)). I am not sure what the conventions are for visualizing it (if there are any), so I drew it so that it encompasses the respective proportion of the full circle. A technical issue one runs into is that using polar coordinates, when this range crosses 0/360 it is not possible to draw it with one segment. Therefore, I had to divide such cases in two parts (before and after 0/360).

```r
mnbears <- bears %>%
  mutate(bearing.circ = circular(bearing, units='degrees', rotation='clock', 
                                 zero=pi/2, modulo='2pi')) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>%
  summarise(mnDir = mean(bearing.circ),
            var = var(bearing.circ)) %>%
  mutate(lower = (mnDir - 180 * var) %% 360,
         upper = (mnDir + 180 * var) %% 360)

# split [lower, upper] ranges which cross zero/360 
#   into [lower, 360] and [0, upper]
cross.zero <- mnbears$lower > mnbears$upper
if (any(cross.zero)) {
  for (i in which(cross.zero)) {
    
    tmp <- mnbears[rep(i, 2), ]
    tmp$upper[1] <- 360
    tmp$lower[2] <- 0
    mnbears <- rbind(mnbears, tmp)
  }
  
  mnbears <- mnbears[-which(cross.zero), ]
}
```

I didn't join `bears` and `mnbears` as the mean/variance segments would be drawn over and over. Also, I had to change `Year` to factor as otherwise there was na error.

```r
bears$Year <- factor(bears$Year)
mnbears$Year <- factor(mnbears$Year)

bDist<-ggplot(bears, aes(x = bearing360, fill = Year)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 15, boundary = -7.5, colour = "black", size = .25) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,360),
                     breaks = seq(0, 360, by = 90),
                     minor_breaks = seq(0, 360, by = 45)) +
  scale_fill_brewer() +
  facet_grid(~Year) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_line(color = "grey"),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 11),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())

bDist + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = mnDir, y = 10, xend = mnDir, yend = 20), col='black', 
               data=mnbears) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = lower, y = 20, xend = upper, yend = 20), col='black', 
               data=mnbears)
```

[image: circular data with mean and variance]